# Breaking checkboxes jquery using form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a custom validation for four fields.  One needs to be filled in.  The validation works but, ruins my checkboxes.  My checkboxes are no longer able to be checked after jquery click function runs.  The checkboxes are using inputs. I am not sure where my jquery is having a problem. Can anyone assist?

jquery below

```
 $('form').click(function (e) {
        if ($('#CoilWeightMIN').val() == '' && $('#CoilWeightMax').val() == '' && $('#IsCoilforCoil').prop('checked', false) && $('#IsStraightenandCut').prop('checked', false)) {
            //alert('Coil Weight must have a field filled in.');
            $("#coil span").text("Coil Weight must have a field filled in.");
            e.preventDefault(e);
        }
    });

    $('form').change(function () {

        if ($('#CoilWeightMIN').val() != "" || $('#CoilWeightMax').val() != "" || $('#IsCoilforCoil').prop('checked', true) || $('#IsStraightenandCut').prop('checked', true)) {
            //alert('Coil Weight must have a field filled in.');
            $("#coil span").text("");
        }
    });
```

HTML below

```
 <div class="row">
            <div id="coil" class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CoilWeightMIN" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CoilWeightMIN" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CoilWeightMIN" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CoilWeightMax" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CoilWeightMax" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="CoilWeightMax" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center col-sm-3">
                <label asp-for="IsCoilforCoil" class="control-label text-center"></label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-offset-5">
                        <input  asp-for="IsCoilforCoil" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center col-sm-3">
                <label asp-for="IsStraightenandCut" class="control-label text-center"></label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-offset-5">
                        <input asp-for="IsStraightenandCut" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: No idea what *"ruins checkboxes"* means. Please be a lot more specific. See [ask]

Comment: try creating a [minimal and verifiable example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so can witness the downfall too.

Comment: Right off the bat, you are doing `$('#check-box-id').prop('checked', false)` in an if statement... This is SETTING the checked property. You want `$('#check-box-id').is(':checked')` in the if statement. I believe this may actually be your issue. When you click or change the form, it is probably triggering that click/change event, which SETS the checked property to false for your checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  The prop vs is was a problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function(){
  if($('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false)){
   console.log('Wah wah, checkbox is always unchecked!');
  }

});

$('#checkbox2').on('change', function(){
  if($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')){
   console.log('Checkbox2 is checked!');
  }
  else{
    console.log('Checkbox2 is not checked :(');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />Checkbox 1

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />Checkbox 2
```

Here is an example based on my comment on your initial post. If you try to check Checkbox1, it will never be checked because the if statement is doing  `$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false)` which always sets the checkbox to unchecked. In my checkbox2 change function, I use .is(':checked'), and you will see that you can click it and work the checkbox correctly, and you get the proper true/false you are after.

Comment: Thank you.  The prop was forcing my checkboxes to force check or uncheck.